# Find the limit $ \frac{(\arctan(2 - x) + \sin(x - 2)^2)}{ x^2 - 4}$ when x -> 2

Tags: calculus

We have to use the $o(\text{o small})$ notation while solving this problem

Answer (score 1):

Let $y=x-2 \to 0$ then

$$\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{\arctan(2 - x) + \sin(x - 2)^2}{ x^2 - 4} = \lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\arctan y + \sin (y^2)}{ y(y+4)} $$

and

- $\arctan y = y+o(y^2)$
- $\sin (y^2) = y^2+o(y^2)$

Comment: I would be more precise and write the error terms as $O(y^3)$ and $O(y^4)$. Actually, in this problem, all you need is $o(y)$.

Comment: Yes of course we can also use Big-O or o(y) to conclude but I prefer expand to the same order. The result follows without any additional difficulty.